# jquery hide only works once

Tags: jquery, hide, show

i have an area which is initially hidden, and should appear/disappear based on a field's content.

so if the user selects  pay by credit card - then the extra fields open, if not - then they disappear.

the problem is that it only works to show them - not hide.

can someone pls see here: http://bit.ly/dOCNQQ

Thanks in advance!

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#CCinfo').hide();       
    $('#paymethod').change(function(){
    var payme = $(this).val();
    if (payme=='CreditCard') {
            $('#CCinfo').show("slow");
        } else {
            $('#CCinfo').hide();    
        }
    });
});

<tr>
 <td colspan="2" align="right">
  <strong>pay by:</strong><br />
  <input type="radio" name="paymethod" id="paymethod" title="*" class="required" value="CreditCard"/>credit card<br />
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" align="right"><strong>pay by:</strong><br />
    <input type="radio" name="paymethod" id="paymethod" title="*" class="required" value="CreditCard"/>credit card<br />&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="paymethod" id="paymethod" title="*" class="required" value="Check"/>cash<br />&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="paymethod" id="paymethod" title="*" class="required" value="At Dinner"/>check
   </td>
  </tr>
  &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="paymethod" id="paymethod" title="*" class="required" value="Check"/>cash<br />&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="paymethod" id="paymethod" title="*" class="required" value="At Dinner"/> check
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is not a "debugging on demand" platform. You will need to extract the code which you think is wrong, post it here, and then somebody will be able to help you. By posting a link to a page and asking for "debugging", you do not contribute anything to the community, because the question you've asked won't be of any use to anyone but you.

Comment: It's cool, I don't mind debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example multiple inputs have the same id, "paymethod", which you then use to listen for a `change` event.  In HTML the id attribute of an element must be unique, when you call `$("#paymethod")` it is only finding the first input with this id.  You should either remove the common id attribute or create unique ones.  You should use the `name` attribute to locate the radio inputs.

So the HTML would be something like this:

```
<td align="right" colspan="2"><strong>pay by:</strong><br>
    <input type="radio" value="CreditCard" class="required" title="*" name="paymethod">credit card<br>&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="Check" class="required" title="*" name="paymethod">cash<br>&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" value="At Dinner" class="required" title="*" name="paymethod"> check
</td>
```

The JS to get the radio elements would be:

```
$("input[name='paymethod']").change(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your radio buttons have the same ID. When you select `$('#paymethod').val()`, you only get the value of the first radio button. Coincidentally, this is always the credit card.

Try:

```
$('input[name="paymethod"]').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.value == 'CreditCard') {
        $('#CCinfo').show("slow");
    } else {
        $('#CCinfo').stop().hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your code. You can't have multiple input elements with the same ID. The reason why this is happening in your code is because the click handler is working for only the first element with ID as paymethod, not the other two. Just use a common class for all of them and bind a click handler to that class.